# For each line in the file, find the immediate next line whose timestamp difference is at least n seconds

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, time-series

I am new to time series programming with Python. Here is the sample file:

```
DateTime<space> Price <space> Data1<space> Data2

Sample file contents:
20171105 09:20:01.134 2123.00 12.23 34.12
20171105 09:20:01.789 2133.00 32.43 45.62
20171105 09:20:02.238 2423.00 35.43 55.62
20171105 09:20:02.567 3423.00 65.43 56.62
20171105 09:20:02.948 2463.00 45.43 58.62

Date Format:
YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss.mi
YYYY => Year
MM => Month starting from 01
DD => Day of month starting from 01
hh => hour
mm => minute
ss => second
mi => milliseconds
```

Assume that we have to shift price by n seconds. For each line in
the file, find the immediate next line whose timestamp difference is at least n seconds. Say we are at line l1 and the immediate next line with timestamp difference as n seconds is l2. Then the shifted time of l1 is Price of l2 - Price of l1.
Lets work out the above logic. Assume shifting time interval is 1 second. Then
the lines which are 1 second apart are:

the pairs (first line, third line), (second line, fifth line). Third, fourth and fifth lines does not have a pair ie there are no lines whose timestamp difference is greater than or equal to 1 second.

Shifted price of first line is 2423.00 - 2123.00 = 300
Shifted price of second line is 2463.00 - 2133.0 = 330
There are no shifted price for line number 3, 4 and 5.

Can someone help me write the code for this in Pandad.. Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
import pandas as pd

# read CSV and parse dates
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', delim_whitespace=True, names=range(5),
                 parse_dates={'date': [0, 1]})

# find indices of shifted values
n = 1
shifted = df['date'] + pd.Timedelta(n, 's')
indices = df['date'].searchsorted(shifted)

# add a column with the shift
df['shift'] = df[2].reindex(indices).reset_index(drop=True) - df[2]
print(df)
```

result is this:

```
                     date       2      3      4  shift
0 2017-11-05 09:20:01.134  2123.0  12.23  34.12  300.0
1 2017-11-05 09:20:01.789  2133.0  32.43  45.62  330.0
2 2017-11-05 09:20:02.238  2423.0  35.43  55.62    NaN
3 2017-11-05 09:20:02.567  3423.0  65.43  56.62    NaN
4 2017-11-05 09:20:02.948  2463.0  45.43  58.62    NaN
```